# How to preserve request url with nginx proxy_pass

Tags: ruby, proxy, nginx, thin, unicorn

I was trying to use [Thin](http://code.macournoyer.com/thin/) app server and had one issue.

When nginx [proxies](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpProxyModule#proxy_pass) the request to Thin (or Unicorn) using `proxy_pass http://my_app_upstream;` the application receives the modified URL sent by nginx (`http://my_app_upstream`).

What I want is to pass the original URL and the original request from client with no modification as the app relies heavily on it.

The nginx' [doc](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpProxyModule#proxy_pass) says:

> If it is necessary to transmit URI in
>   the unprocessed form then directive
>   proxy_pass should be used without URI
>   part.

But I don't understand how exactly to configure that as the related sample is actually using URI:

```
location  /some/path/ {
  proxy_pass   http://127.0.0.1;
}
```

So could you please help me figuring out how to **preserve the original request URL** from the client?

Comment: "Thin" now points to a 404

Answer (score 178, accepted):

I think the [`proxy_set_header`](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_set_header) directive could help:

```
location / {
    proxy_pass http://my_app_upstream;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    # ...
}
```

Comment: Note to other people finding this: The heart of the solution to make nginx not manipulate the URL, is to remove the slash at the end of the `proxy_pass` directive. `http://my_app_upstream` vs `http://my_app_upstream/`

Comment: For me what was happening is that when JSP was doing redirect, my_app_upstream host name was showing up. Using `proxy_set_header Host $host` modified and made Tomcat/JSP to think that it's an actual client requested domain. Thanks for the help

Comment: @HugoJosefson wow thanks god I notice your post. This should be explicit in the answer

Comment: In my case, @HugoJosefson's solution would not work. I was pointing to http://localhost:port; I had to set the header.

Comment: It's an improvement but the scheme (http or https) is not preserved. Now my `https://example.com/page` uris become `http://example.com/page`

Comment: @HugoJosefson should be knighted

Comment: I'm trying the same thing but it's not preserving the url.. I'm getting just "GET / HTTP/1.0" instead of url.. What should I do?

Answer (score 13):

Just 
proxy_set_header Host $host
 miss port for my case. Solved by:

```
    location / {
     proxy_pass http://BACKENDIP/;
     include /etc/nginx/proxy.conf;
    }
```

and then in the proxy.conf

```
    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_set_header Host $host:$server_port;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
```

Comment: Thanks, this was the piece I was missing (the $server_port) to get OAuth verification working on the endpoint behind the proxy.

Comment: I'm using rack-protection with sinatra and was getting Forbidden on POST URLs. Adding the port to the Host proxy header fixed it for me.

Comment: this doesn't work anymore in latest versions of Nginx I think http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31482796/why-is-proxy-set-header-host-host-no-longer-working-in-nginx-1-8-0?s=1|3.2072

Answer (score 11):

nginx also provides the $http_host variable which will pass the port for you.
its a concatenation of host and port.

So u just need to do:

```
proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
```

Answer (score 9):

In case something modifies the location that you're trying to serve, e.g. `try_files`, this preserves the request for the back-end:

```
location / {
  proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080$request_uri;
}
```

Answer (score 8):

> Note to other people finding this: The heart of the solution to make
>   nginx not manipulate the URL, is to remove the slash at the end of the
>   Copy: proxy_pass directive. http://my_app_upstream vs 
>   http://my_app_upstream/ – Hugo Josefson

I found this above in the comments but I think it really should be an answer.

Answer (score 4):

To perfectly forward without chopping the `absoluteURI` of the request and the `Host` in the header:

```
server {
    listen 35005;

    location / {
        rewrite            ^(.*)$   "://$http_host$uri$is_args$args";
        rewrite            ^(.*)$   "http$uri$is_args$args" break;
        proxy_set_header   Host     $host;

        proxy_pass         https://deploy.org.local:35005;
    }
}
```

Found here: https://opensysnotes.wordpress.com/2016/11/17/nginx-proxy_pass-with-absolute-url/

Comment: Velkan, but why it is cannot be done in one rewrite?

Comment: @MikhailPolitaev the first "rewrite" seems unnecessary. The source article has a "break" in the first "rewrite" and a comment that says to remove that "break" to make it work. So the source isn't really reliable.

Comment: First break is unnecessary, agreed. But already realized why 2 rewrite required. Because if rewrite start with "https://" Nginx will respond 301 or 302 to the client and here 2 rewrite split https:// to 2 parts "https" and "://" in result redirect not returned to the client and send in absolute form "https://..." in GET request what is required by proxy protocol. I didn't find another way how to make GET request in absolute form – starts with scheme http(s):// it's strange that not obvious in Nginx.

Answer (score 2):

In my scenario i have make this via below code in nginx vhost configuration

```
server {
server_name dashboards.etilize.com;

location / {
    proxy_pass http://demo.etilize.com/dashboards/;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
}}
```

$http_host will set URL in Header same as requested

Answer (score -1):

for my auth server...  this works. i like to have options for /auth for my own humanized readability...  or also i have it configured by port/upstream for machine to machine.

## .

## at the beginning of conf

```
####################################################
upstream auth {
    server 127.0.0.1:9011 weight=1 fail_timeout=300s;
    keepalive 16;
  }
```

## Inside my 443 server block

```
          if (-d $request_filename) {
          rewrite [^/]$ $scheme://$http_host$uri/ permanent;
      }

  location /auth {
          proxy_pass http://$http_host:9011;
          proxy_set_header Origin           http://$host;
          proxy_set_header Host             $http_host:9011;
          proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For  $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
          proxy_set_header Upgrade          $http_upgrade;
          proxy_set_header Connection       $http_connection;
          proxy_http_version 1.1;
      }
```

## At the bottom of conf

```
#####################################################################
#                                                                   #
#     Proxies for all the Other servers on other ports upstream     #
#                                                                   #
#####################################################################


#######################
#        Fusion       #
#######################

server {
    listen 9001 ssl;

#############  Lock it down  ################

# SSL certificate locations
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/allineed.app/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/allineed.app/privkey.pem;

# Exclusions

    include snippets/exclusions.conf;

# Security

    include snippets/security.conf;
    include snippets/ssl.conf;

# Fastcgi cache rules

    include snippets/fastcgi-cache.conf;
    include snippets/limits.conf;
    include snippets/nginx-cloudflare.conf;

###########  Location upstream ##############

    location  ~ / {
        proxy_pass http://auth;
        proxy_set_header Origin           http://$host;
        proxy_set_header Host             $host:$server_port;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For  $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade          $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection       $http_connection;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
    }
        if (-d $request_filename) {
        rewrite [^/]$ $scheme://$http_host$uri/ permanent;
    }
}
```