# Nginx per location / pass rewriten uri to proxy_pass

Tags: url, nginx, url-rewriting, proxypass

What the quickest and cleanest solution if you want to proxy URL request to two different backends via proxypass based on location.

```
location /app1/ {
    alias /var/www/ruby/public;
    proxy_set_header  X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header  Host $http_host;
    proxy_redirect    off;
    try_files $uri $uri/ @ruby;
}

location @ruby {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000;
}

location /app2/ {
    proxy_set_header  X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header  Host $http_host;
    proxy_redirect    off;
    try_files $uri $uri/ @other;
}

location @other {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;
}
```

With this config nginx pass "/app1" or "/app2" to proxy and backend doesn't recognize the url/command ..

as for instance would like to pass to `http://127.0.0.1:3000` only `/messages` when accessing `http://<nginx>/app1/messages` - but in configuration above also pass `/app1/` as `http://127.0.0.1:3000/app1/messages`. Same goes for `/app2`

Answer (score 15):

Try putting "/" at the end of upstream name
e.g

```
proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080/;
```

Please see this post:
[How to preserve request url with nginx proxy_pass](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5834025/how-to-preserve-request-url-with-nginx-proxy-pass)

Comment: This does not work due to `"proxy_pass cannot have URI part in location given by regular expression..."`, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21662940/proxy-pass-cannot-have-uri-part-in-location.