# nginx 'proxy_pass' cannot have URI part in location?

Tags: nginx

I have a `location` block as

```
location @test{
    proxy_pass http://localhost:5000/1;
}
```

but nginx complains that `"proxy_pass cannot have URI part in location given by regular expression..."` Does anyone know what might be wrong?

I'm trying to query localhost:5000/1 when an upload is complete:

```
location /upload_attachment {
    upload_pass @test;
    upload_store /tmp;
    ...
}
```

Comment: add a trailing `/` after the `1`, make it `http://localhost:5000/1/`;

Comment: @MohammadAbuShady Same error, I'm afraid.

Comment: well then maybe try the other way around, use the base proxy `localhost:5000` but run a rewrite before it, `rewrite ^ /1$1 last`

Comment: @MohammadAbuShady perfect! Do you know where this is actually documented?

Comment: Don't know if there's a documentation for this, but I'll explain it in an answer

Answer (score 65, accepted):

Technically just adding the URI should work, because it's [documented here](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpProxyModule#proxy_pass) and it says that it should work, so

```
location @test{
    proxy_pass http://localhost:5000/1/; # with a trailing slash
}
```

Should have worked fine, but since you said it didn't I suggested the other way around, the trick is that instead of passing `/my/uri` to `localhost:5000/1`, we pass `/1/my/uri` to `localhost:5000`,

That's what my rewrite did

```
rewrite ^ /1$1
```

Meaning rewrite the whole URL, prepend it with `/1` then add the remaining, the whole block becomes

```
location @test{
    rewrite ^ /1$1;
    proxy_pass http://localhost:5000;
}
```

**Note:** *@Fleshgrinder [provided an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21662940/proxy-pass-cannot-have-uri-part-in-location/21714937#21714937) explaining why the first method didn't work.*

Comment: Could you please provide a non-broken link for the following? It returns 404. https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/HttpProxyModule#proxy_pass

Comment: Thanks in my case I should add break `rewrite ^ /search$1 break;` or it will have this error: `rewrite or internal redirection cycle while processing "/search`

Comment: How rewrite will work if the `proxy_pass` is not `localhost` ?

Answer (score 57):

### What's actually happening here?

nginx cannot process your desired URI part in the `proxy_pass` directive because you're within a named location (hence the error message). This is because nginx is built in a modular fashion and each configuration block is read in various stages by the various modules. So just remember that you cannot have a URI within your `proxy_pass` directive in the following cases:

1. Regular Expression Locations
2. Named Locations
3. `if` Blocks

### How could we solve this problem?

Mohammad AbuShady [explained](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21680744/2737435) how to do a rewrite and pass the requested URI to the proxy server. I just wanted to clarify the reason.

Answer (score 17):

Try omitting the "/" (URI part) and check.

```
location @test{
    proxy_pass http://localhost:5000;
}
```

Comment: Yes, that'd work. However, I'd like it to be directed to localhost:5000/1. I'm trying to query that URI when an upload is complete. I've extended my original question now and hopefully it'll be more clear.

Comment: @Kate Ok. So that is working.You'd like it to be directed to localhost:5000/1 ..let me check.

Comment: This was exactly the problem with my config. I didn't realize that you couldn't have a trailing "/"

Answer (score 0):

None of the above helped me.

My workaround is:

```
location @cat {
    resolver 8.8.8.8 valid=30s;
    set $upstream https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/53/Sheba1.JPG;
    proxy_pass $upstream;
}
```

Note that a `resolver` [directive](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#resolver) might differ regarding your context.