# "proxy_pass" cannot have URI part in location given by regular expression inside "if"

Tags: nginx, nginx-location

I want to match request parameter and direct to my gateway, I do like this

*location /app/share {*

```
if ($args ~ action=encode) {
        proxy_pass http://192.168.1.249:11201/openmallservice/corp/app/share/;
    }
```

}

what's wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21680744/1713660).

`/some-url/` part is not allowed in `proxy_pass` in `if` statement and regular expressions like `location ~ whatever`

```
# add uri here and break to stop searching another locations
rewrite ^(.*)$ /your-path$1 break;
# proxy without uri
proxy_pass http://111.222.33.44:8000;
```