# How to preserve request url with nginx proxy_pass on Mac OSX

Tags: macos, nginx, proxy, proxypass

I've follow the instructions asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5834025/how-to-preserve-request-url-with-nginx-proxy-pass), but it still changes the request url for both 80 and 443 server, does anybody have the same issue?

I'am using the **OS X El Capitan 10.11.4**, and I use the same nginx.conf and it works perfectly and preserves the request url on **Ubuntu 12.04.5 LTS**.

Below is my proxy setting.

```
location / {
    proxy_pass   http://my_app_upstream/;
    proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP       $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_set_header        Host            $host;
}
```

for the installation I use `brew install nginx` on Mac and self-compiled one on Ubuntu

Comment: What do mean when you say the request URL changes? What does it change from/to? In the link that you provided, it is also noted that you should not include / when proxy_passing. So try `proxy_pass http://my_app_upstream;` instead of `proxy_pass http://my_app_upstream/;` and see if it helps.

Comment: okay, I'll try it next Monday and be back, thank you.

Comment: @iownthegame, ping, have you tried yet?

Comment: I've tried.... and it's my mistake actually :(  Ngix did `proxy_pass`, but my code redirect the page again.... so both with or without slash work for me :p  I vote you but I cannot mark it as answer, sorry and thank you anyway.

Comment: @iownthegame, thanks for upvote!  you should probably still accept some answer if the problem is resolved, so that the question does not show up as unsolved.

Comment: @cnst thanks for your reminder!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want the URL to change (e.g., due to [Nginx pass_proxy subdirectory without url decoding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28684300/nginx-pass-proxy-subdirectory-without-url-decoding/37584637#37584637)), you should omit the trailing slash from your [`proxy_pass`](http://nginx.org/r/proxy_pass):

```
-proxy_pass   http://my_app_upstream/;
+proxy_pass   http://my_app_upstream;
```