# Trying to root a domain with Nginx under a sub-folder

Tags: nginx, dns, subdirectory

I have a domain tmhos.church and a simple index.html located at cosmoscomputers.com:3597/ref/tmhos.  (they're on the same digital ocean droplet server & dns)

I'm trying to hide tmhos.church so that it appears to be its own website, while actually being at above /ref/tmhos.

I have found this article [How to preserve request url with nginx proxy_pass](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5834025/how-to-preserve-request-url-with-nginx-proxy-pass) (close i think, but not exactly my problem) and have an nginx config that looks like below... but when i go to tmhos.church, it goes to the top of cosmoscomputers.com (but does keep the tmhos.church domain in the address bar (good)).  If I then manually add /ref/tmhos to the end, it goes to the page i want to be the root.  I confess i don't know what ALL the lines are doing (eg the 'rewrite' regex), but the proxy_pass isn't doing exactly what i want.

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    server_name tmhos.church www.tmhos.church;

    location / {

        rewrite            ^(.*)$   "://$http_host$uri$is_args$args";
        rewrite            ^(.*)$   "http$uri$is_args$args" break;
        proxy_set_header   Host     $host;

        proxy_pass http://138.197.133.227:3597/ref/tmhos;

    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
    }

    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you please try:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    server_name tmhos.church www.tmhos.church;

    location / {
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_pass http://cosmoscomputers.com:3597/ref/tmhos/;
    }

    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }
}
```

Comment: Amazing what the slash on the END does... it works!

Comment: yes. and also you had a lot of other stuff in the config that did not make sense to me. does it work as expected?

Comment: Perfectly, in all testing so far... THX!

Comment: Please be sure to accept the answer as the correct one if everything works, thanks!

Comment: Ya, i was trying to... don't see how to do that... I even tried upvoting, but i don't have enough credits yet.  Tried the "Answer Your Question" button, but it leaves a field for ME to answer (not accept yours)... do you know how?

Comment: There should be a big check mark right under the answer "down vote" button. Clicking on that should do it :)